# Passing AJAX Response in HTML Heading Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm currently unable to pass my Ajax response in HTML Heading tag.
The ajax query:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ws/api/report/facts",
     success: function (response) { 
        var data = JSON.parse(response)[0].centers;
        var result = $('<h3 />').append(data).find('#myHeading').html(); 
        $('#myHeading').html(result);
     }
});
```

And this is my HTML where i want to pass my Ajax Response:

**HTML TAG**

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:60px;"></i>
   <h3 id="#myHeading"></h3>
</div>
```

Any sort of help would be grateful.

Comment: What exactly the problem? Do you get response from the server? Please not  that your url includes some invalid character `${`.

Comment: The issue got solved.. 
Thanks to @Mustapha Larhrouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the html of #myHeading by the data:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ws/api/report/facts",
     success: function(response) { 
        var data = JSON.parse(response)[0].centers;
        $('#myHeading').html(data);
     }
});
```

and in your html replace `#myHeading` with `myHeading`:

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:60px;"></i>
   <h3 id="myHeading"></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL looks invalid, should either be:

```
url: pageContext.request.contextPath + "/ws/api/report/facts",
```

or (as ES6 template literal):

```
url: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ws/api/report/facts`,
```